# バッチファイルで%~dp0の末尾のディレクトリセパレータを取り除く方法

Tags: batch-file

バッチファイル内で%~dp0とすると実行中のバッチファイルのディレクトリパスを取得できますが、末尾に`\`が付いてきてしまい、これが不便なことがあります。

下記のように末尾のセパレータなしで実行中のバッチファイルのパスを取得できないでしょうか。

```
X C:\home\local\
O C:\home\local
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SET DIR=%~dp0
ECHO %DIR:~0,-1%
```

一旦、環境変数に格納するとその値を編集することができます。

`%DIR:~0,-1%`で`%DIR%`の末尾の位置文字を削った文字列を得ることができます。